# How can I rewrite this code to solve error x not in list

Tags: python, list, valueerror, vertices

I am a new member. In this code, I am trying to remove an item from a list created from graph.keys. I use Mac OS 10.11.6 and Wing IDLE 101.
Error: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

```
import math
import RegExService
import random
import numpy
from functools import reduce
import sys
import getopt
import time

alfa = 2
beta = 5
sigm = 3
ro = 0.8
th = 80
fileName = "medium.txt"
iterations = 10
ants = 22


#Draw the graph
def generateGraph():
    capacityLimit, graph, demand, optimalValue = RegExService.getData(fileName)
    vertices = list(graph.keys())
    vertices.remove(0)
```

Comment: Where is the code?

Comment: Questions with images of code (even if they are invisible, as in this case, since there's no reference in the text to your code-note) are subject to instant closure. Please post your code as ***text!***

Comment: I edited it above. Thanks alot

Comment: @paul-shuvo Thank you, I meet mistake while adding an image. I posted my code above.

Comment: What is your error? You still haven't told us your error. Could you give some error code?

Comment: The error is ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

Comment: Thank you for your considering, I added it above. I hope you can help me to fix it.